# Resistors in Parallel or Series?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, parallel, series, thevenin

Given the following posistions of resistors as a part of a bigger circuit, how can I simplify it? The wire between R1 and R2 is a short as I am using Thevenin's theorem. I've tried to make R1 and R2 and R3 parallel but the answer for the whole circuit doesn't match with the answer that comes on when i simulate it on circuit maker! HELP

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWeuXQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It can't be simplified.

Comment: You can, however, do a delta-star conversion.

Comment: haven't covered that but will try to, thanks!

Comment: Because the resistor combination shows three open nodes it is necessary to know (a) between which nodes the resistance is wanted and (b) what happens with the third node (open or grounded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resistors are in a Delta configuration. Use the Y-Delta transformation to changes their configuration to a Y configuration.

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform